# Esoteric problem: Raspbian Buster vs Ethernet

Tags: pi-3, ethernet, raspbian-buster, raspbian-lite

My RPI3 was working fine with Debian 9 (Raspbian). Today, due to a power outage caused by a storm, SD card stopped booting. I've reinstalled Debian 10 (Raspbian Lite; notice the version change 9 » 10), and after some hours of diag (inlcuding: putting same card to another RPI2, change IP address to static with both DHCPCD and old method) the RPI was not even recognized by the router, not even local `ping` works, only to localhost (which is using loopback interface).

Then I turned on WiFi, and it worked. So the problem is the Ethernet. As I said, I've tried it with 2 RPIs, so it's not a hardware or cabling issue.

Finally, I've found a solution in a forum (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1536428#p1536428), it says that Ethernet card should be set to 100 Mbps.

```
$ sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full
```

And it works :) *For 5-7 secs* :( Check this, I've never seen like this before:

```
# ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full ; ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=92.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=7.11 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=5.55 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=5.84 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=5.29 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=5.57 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=5.58 ms
From 192.168.1.111: icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.111: icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.111: icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.111: icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
```

If I run the command again, I got similar result. I put the `ethtool` command in `/etc/rc.local`, but as it "expires" soon, it's not a solution.

How can I set the Ethernet speed permanently? Or, is there any better solution for this problem? I don't want to use WiFi (it's a file server), the best workaround so far is downgrading to Debian 9.

Comment: Try Raspbian not Debian. Don't put anything in rc.local (it's obsolete). What model Pi?

Comment: It's a RPI3. Quad-core with 4 USB ports, wifi, but not the new one. Ops, I wrote RPI2 in the question, edited. The OS is the official Raspbian, I've tried lite and desktop version https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

Comment: Put the Phone model & OS into tags. DO NOT use Debian (unless you are actually using it Debian ≠ Raspbian).
I don't know why so many Pi users try to set static IP addresses - particularly as they don't understand networking and get it wrong. 
If you want help you have to explain what **YOU** did! Better still use DHCP!

Comment: Don't try to follow links for the Pi4 - all other models only use 100MHz (unless using an ancient router).

Comment: This is my home server, connected to a switch, so it works w/o router and DHCP, that's why it has static IP.

I use Raspbian.

The fact that it works for a while when I set Ethernet speed to 100 MHz, is probably a symptom, not the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried my RetroPie machine today, and realized that it has similar problems, no connection on Ethernet.

I have a switch attached to the router (so the local network can alive without switch). At the switch, the plug of the Ethernet cable, which comes from the router, was a half millimeter off from the socket. Yes, its picker (what-its-name, it should hold the plug tight, which, when you plug it in, says: *click*) is not working, just as in case of 50% of the CAT5 plugs I ever met.

Unfortunatley, this half millimeter gap was enough for a slower speed.

Thanks for all the technical and moral support!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.